List each message from table A with it's earliest response in table B, chronologically
I have three tables: conversations, user_messages and system_messages. Their basic structure (irrelevant columns removed for brevity) is:
create table conversations(id int generated by default as identity primary key);

create table user_messages(
   id int generated by default as identity primary key
  ,conversation_id int references conversations(id)
  ,content text
  ,created_at timestamp);

create table system_messages(
   id int generated by default as identity primary key
  ,conversation_id int references conversations(id)
  ,content text
  ,created_at timestamp);

I am trying to generate an export of "system said X" and "user responded with Y" rows for a given conversation. The issue I'm having is finding a way to ensure that the "user responded with Y" message corresponds to the chronologically next message in the conversation, following the system message. So output would look something like:



system_said
user_said




Hi!
Hello


How's it going?
I'm alright, you?


I'm good!
Nice.




Approach 1: This works, but with a poor and inefficient query, using a sub-query that references outer values.
SELECT
    content AS system_said, (
        SELECT content
        FROM user_messages
        WHERE conversation_id = sm.conversation_id AND created_at > sm.created_at
        ORDER BY created_at
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS user_said
FROM system_messages sm
WHERE sm.conversation_id = ?


Approach 2: This is where I'm stuck. I'm trying to rewrite the above more efficiently using a proper join, but I can't force the join to give me the chronologically next message, so I'm getting mixed up pairs like:



system_said
user_said




Hi!
Nice.


How's it going?
Hello


I'm good!
I'm alright, you?



Here's the query:
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON (sm) sm.id AS message,
    sm.content AS system_said,
    um.content AS user_said
FROM system_messages sm
JOIN (
    SELECT conversation_id, created_at, content
    FROM user_messages
    ORDER BY created_at
) um ON um.conversation_id = sm.conversation_id AND um.created_at > sm.created_at
ORDER BY sm
WHERE c.id = ?

(I found I had to add in DISTINCT ON () otherwise I got duplicate rows.)


What's the best way to approach this?
[ EDIT ]
Clarification: messages always alternate from system message to user message to system message and so on. There would never be two messages chronologically adjacent from the same source.

Your idea with distinct on sounds good, but there are a few things you could improve:

You don't need the subquery, you can join directly.
Distinct on(sm) checks the entire record FROM system_messages sm. Since it has a primary key, distinct on(sm.id) is sufficient.
The order by you use with distinct on could use more than just the unique column. If you want the soonest response, add its timestamp: order by sm.id,um.created_at.

In a demo at db<>fiddle with 20k conversations and 200k messages in them, this takes 40ms:
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON (sm.id) sm.id AS message,
    sm.content AS system_said,
    um.content AS user_said
FROM system_messages sm
JOIN user_messages um 
   ON um.conversation_id = sm.conversation_id 
  AND um.created_at > sm.created_at
  AND sm.conversation_id = 1
ORDER BY sm.id,um.created_at;

You can also add covering indexes to speed things up with index-only scans, which reduces the exec time below 1ms:
create index on user_messages(conversation_id,created_at)
   include(content,id);
create index on system_messages(conversation_id,created_at)
   include(content,id);

With those in place, it looks like your initial idea wins performance wise, whether you push down the correlated scalar subquery down to be cross joined with, as a lateral suqbuery doing the exact same thing, or not:  demo2 at db<>fiddle
SELECT sm.content AS system_said,
       um.content AS user_said
FROM system_messages sm
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT content
    FROM   user_messages um
    WHERE um.conversation_id = sm.conversation_id 
      AND um.created_at > sm.created_at
    ORDER BY um.created_at
    LIMIT 1 ) um
WHERE sm.conversation_id = 999
ORDER BY sm.created_at;


Thank you for this - much appreciated. I've plugged both your queries into my wider query (there are more joins, columns etc.) and I'm definitely finding that the DISTINCT ON variant is considerably faster. But both work identically. I'll try adding the cover indexes (thanks for introducing me to those) to see if I can speed this up further.

Use a CTE to rank user messages within each conversation based on their creation time and then use a JOIN to pair each system message with the next user message using the row number. Try this:
WITH ranked_user_messages AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        conversation_id,
        content,
        created_at,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY conversation_id ORDER BY created_at) AS rn
    FROM user_messages
)
SELECT
    sm.content AS system_said,
    um.content AS user_said
FROM system_messages sm
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT content
    FROM user_messages um
    WHERE um.conversation_id = sm.conversation_id
      AND um.created_at > sm.created_at
    ORDER BY um.created_at
    LIMIT 1
) um ON true
WHERE sm.conversation_id = ?
ORDER BY sm.created_at;


Yup, that'll be all the complex bits of Postgres I mentioned I didn't know! Many thanks for this - I'll give it a go and accept if it works.

The CTE isn't used anywhere, so it's just noise that the planner will discard. The rest is OP's original query, with the subquery pushed from being a correlated scalar suqbuery in the select list, down to the from list as a lateral subquery, which does the same exact thing, and also seems to perform exactly the same.

I would try:
Schema (PostgreSQL v15)
create table system_messages (
  id serial primary key,
  conversation_id int,
  content text,
  created_at timestamp
);

create table user_messages (
  id serial primary key,
  conversation_id int,
  content text,
  created_at timestamp
);

insert into system_messages(conversation_id, content, created_at) values
   (1, 'Hi!', '2024-05-31 08:00:00'),
   (1, 'How''s it going?', '2024-05-31 08:01:00'),
   (1, 'I''m good!', '2024-05-31 08:02:00');

insert into user_messages(conversation_id, content, created_at) values
   (1, 'Hello', '2024-05-31 08:00:30'),
   (1, 'I''m alright, you?', '2024-05-31 08:01:30'),
   (1, 'Nice.', '2024-05-31 08:02:30');


Query #1
with s_m (r_n, system_said) as (
  select row_number() over (order by created_at),
         content
  from system_messages
  where conversation_id = 1
),
u_m (r_n, player_said) as (
  select row_number() over (order by created_at),
         content
  from user_messages
  where conversation_id = 1
)
select s_m.system_said, u_m.player_said from
s_m join u_m on s_m.r_n = u_m.r_n
order by s_m.r_n;




system_said
player_said




Hi!
Hello


How's it going?
I'm alright, you?


I'm good!
Nice.




View on DB Fiddle

The "ensure that the "user responded with Y" message corresponds to the chronologically next message in the conversation, following the system message" isn't satisfied here. If Nth message from the user comes precedes rather than follows the system message, it still gets matched. Your fiddle link is empty, so I moved it here - as demonstrated, it only maintains the order of their individual messages, but the conversation is out of sync. If the user said all 3 of their lines yesterday, they'll still get matched with system's 3 messages from today

@Zegarek I'm selecting only messages from both tables that share a common conversation_id and my assumption is that for a given conversation_id (1 in this example), the conversation alters between the system and the user so that, for example, the lowest creation date for a user reply must be between the lowest and next lowest creation dates for a system message (see the creation dates I have used for both tables). In that case, converting a creation date to a row number (which is what I am doing in essence) should allow me to match up row numbers as I have been doing. What is out of sync?

Sure, if the data was constrained this way, it would work. I was just pointing out OP doesn't mention anything like that, and this post didn't mention it only works if that assumption is true, which I figured would be worth pointing out, especially since the other queries including OP's own, work fine regardless of that assumption. The "out of sync" thing is shown in the demo: shifting messages around whacks the conversation out of sync compared to what timestamps would indicate.

@Zegarek I am not sure I still follow you. I don't really care what the actual timestamps are; I am just using them to order the messages for a given conversation_id and joining the system and user messages based on their order.

This assumption is safe, and one I should have mentioned in my post (I'll edit it). That is, messages always proceed in sequence - first a system message, then a user message, then a system message, and so on. There would never be two messages from the same source one after the other. Thanks for your help, incidentally, both.
